# Differente Time drift between Prometheus container and host machine Oracle Linux 8.7 - Cant synchronize with NTP

Tags: docker, time, synchronization, prometheus, ntp

I have an issue with time in Prometheus Container  running on Oracle Linux 8.0.
I´ve installed OS with minimal options, after,  i ran this commands to adjustime date time.

```
dnf update
dnf -y install chrony
systemctl enable chronyd
vi /etc/chrony.conf
Server <ip ntp server>
chronyc sources
timedatectl set-ntp true
timedatectl set-timezone "America/Sao_Paulo"
timedatectl
```

After that, i installed docker and docker-compose with this commands.

--Docker

```
dnf install -y dnf-utils
dnf config-manager --add-repo=https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
dnf install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
systemctl enable docker
systemctl start docker
```

--Docker-Compose

```
curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.29.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

I ran by docker compose  a conteiner with Prometheus with the follow config:

```
version: '3.0'

networks:   monitor-net:
    driver: bridge

services:   prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    container_name: prometheus
    environment:
      - TZ="America/Sao_Paulo"
    volumes:
      - /opt/prometheus/config:/etc/prometheus
      - /opt/prometheus/data:/prometheus
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
      - '--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus'
      - '--web.console.libraries=/etc/prometheus/console_libraries'
      - '--web.console.templates=/etc/prometheus/consoles'
      - '--storage.tsdb.retention.time=200h'
      - '--web.enable-lifecycle'
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
    networks:
      - monitor-net
    labels:
      org.label-schema.group: "monitoring"
```

But the time between both are differents,  im Brazil the UTC is -3 like is  ok in host machine, but in conteiner is UTC time.

```
[root@monitorpoc mon-central]# date
Fri Mar 31 14:28:11 -03 2023
[root@monitorpoc mon-central]# docker exec -it prometheus /bin/sh
/prometheus $ date
Fri Mar 31 17:28:44 UTC 2023
/prometheus $
```

I was looking many articles in differents places, including Docker official site, and was in Prometheus blog i found the follow:

[Can I change the timezone? Why is everything in UTC?](https://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/faq/#can-i-change-the-timezone-why-is-everything-in-utc)

Exists some way to configure a conteiner to syncronize your internal clock with host clock? Someone alredy have this situation with Prometheus or onother situation and can solve?

I think there is no sense in avoid this, Prometheus have a Time Series Database and like all database, the information must by consistent with timestamp.
This case all the information records out of UTC is terrible wrong like reality

Comment: Like it's said in linked blog - usage of UTC at backend simplifies things and can be negated at UI level (for example in Grafana you see data converted to your local time). Why do you need local time at prometheus? Or do you plan not to use Grafana (or alternatives)?